# change user agent in mplayer windows cmd?

Tags: mplayer, live555

I am viewing a video from rtsp://r5---sn-  link and i wish to change the current user agent that shows up as 
`User-Agent: MPlayer (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2013.04.30)\r\n`
in wireshark.

I also tried the command

```
mplayer -user-agent "QuickTime" rtsp://r5---sn-q4flrne6.googlevideo.com/Cj0LENy73wIaNAkbOZCZD61_VhMYESARFC3vKLxZMOCoAUIASARgxPz01cadit5ZigELM3cxNEhielBxdzQM/D3EFB0C52E0C6FD06FA36F7D5E413993EB5B33D9.90DD45248D796A1FCF6B0E3031CDB810A641A0D6/yt6/1/video.3gp
```

it dont change anything still has the default mplayer user agent

how will i go around changing that to a custom one anybody kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

The mplayer help explain this is for HTTP:

> -user-agent 
>                  Use  as user agent for HTTP streaming.

If you look at mpayer source code [demux_rtp.cpp](https://github.com/pigoz/mplayer-svn/blob/master/libmpdemux/demux_rtp.cpp) you will see that there is no way to specify the user-agent string used by `RTSPClient`.

In order to set it you could call the live555 API of class `RTSPClient`:

```
void    setUserAgentString (char const *userAgentName)
```